# Sending too much data over websocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, rabbitmq

I think I'm having issues sending too much data over a socket.io connection. I'm subscribing to a RabbitMQ exchange and sending data messages to the client for graphing real-time:

```
q.subscribe({routingKeyInPayload:true},function (message) {
  socket.emit('message', {
    key: message._routingKey,
    //msg: decodeURIComponent(message.data),
    client: qName,
    ts: new Date()
  });
  console.log('broadcasting: ' + message._routingKey);
});
```

You can see that "msg" is commented out. When I comment this out, I am able to send ~100-200 messages/second (~800/s peak). However, when the "msg" is included in the JSON data, I get the following error:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

I'm not sure what the error actually is or how to handle it. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: A typical message looks like (I've sanitized the userid's just in case):

```
{"key":"message.1","client":"7raQ6vpCO-PZ5ZTWQVD9","ts":"2013-09-12T22:19:06.677Z"}]}
{"fromuserid": 62XXXX34, "deleted": 0, "messagetype": 1, "datetime": 1379024283000, "touserid": 12XXXX41, "message": "Bored lol, really bored lol", "id": 27963323859}
```

Comment: Any chance you can paste in what the message actually is? Otherwise you're asking for one heck of a shot-in-the-dark answer.

Comment: Try catching the uncaught exceptions to see a more detailed error.

Comment: @Stephen I edited the post with an example of a data message.

Comment: @hexacyanide So one thing I'm not clear on is try/catch in Node. If the function I'm calling does not have an explicit err callback, how would you implement it? That is something that eludes me.

Comment: The `catch` will catch any error thrown inside the `try` block. You don't need to implement anything. However, what I meant was `process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) { // log err });`.

Comment: hey, thanks. I have to read up on process. I assume it's async and can be placed anywhere in my server script.

Comment: `process` is a global object which is an instance of `EventEmitter`. It is useful for things such as timing, memory usage, process management, etc.

Comment: Sending even 100 messages in a second, if this is used for rendering - is generally pointless frequency, as rendering in perfect conditions can't be faster than 60 frames a second.
So actually sending less - is always better. For optimisations I would suggest group messages into bigger ones with more minified json object, as well as consider sending only delta data rather than full objects that have a lot of repetitive information.